# Change comma with dot for sub unitary values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with comma separated values such as `1,6` and `8`.
I tried the following code in a BigQuery and it works for `1,6` but for `,8` the result is `-.8`. How can I change it to `0.8` number format?

```sql
SELECT 
    column_name, 
    REPLACE(column_name,',','.') AS Price 
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example to format your data based on BigQuery [formatting syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format)

```sql
WITH `table_name` AS (
   SELECT '1.6' as column_name UNION ALL
   SELECT '.8'
)

SELECT 
    column_name, 
    format("%g",CAST(REPLACE(column_name,',','.') AS FLOAT64)) AS Price 
FROM `table_name`
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: @RazvanSiu, Great, Can you please accept and vote-up the answer for others to see. This link explain what to do in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers