# How can i ingest a csv file in Google cloud Bigquery with comma inside few data rows and use comma as delimiter?

Tags: google-bigquery

The issue is it is not able to distinguish the delimiter which is comma with the one present in data row and thus giving an error while ingesting into bigquery.
Is there any way?

Comment: Is the issue in using a CSV file, using a comma in data, or both? Providing a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've done already would help show what the issue is. Also, is this relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615070/change-comma-with-dot-for-sub-unitary-values

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict with the comma. If the comma is required to be used in the strings as I suppose to, you only have an option:

- Export the data from source as a CSV with a different delimiter. And when you load the CSV file into BQ you can change the delimiter with the option [Field delimiter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) (Tab, Pipe, or Custom).

Please note that if your csv has already a comma as a separator and a comma in the strings, it won't be possible for BQ to separate as you expect.